# How to break a loop if there's no remaining zero in the array?(C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

The user will play a matching game. If the item matches the number, it'll say it matched otherwise, it won't match. All of the matched number are passed on the matchedNum array. The initial value of the matchedNum array is zeroes. How do i stop the loop when there's no more zeroes in the array?

```
class Program
{
    public static int[,] memoryNum = { { 2, 1, 7, 3 }, { 5, 4, 9, 6 }, { 3, 7, 2, 4 }, { 6, 5, 1, 9 } };
    public static int[,] matchedNum = { { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
    public static int row1 = 0;
    public static int col1 = 0;
    public static int row2 = 0;
    public static int col2 = 0;
    public Boolean matches = true;
    public static int tries = 3;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("* ");
                if (j == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
        }

        while (tries != 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter row(First Num): ");
            row1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            checker(row1);
            Console.Write("Enter col(First Num): ");
            col1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            checker(col1);
            Console.Write("Enter row(Second Num): ");
            row2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            checker(row2);
            Console.Write("Enter col(Second Num): ");
            col2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            checker(col2);

            if (memoryNum[row1 - 1, col1 - 1] == memoryNum[row2 - 1, col2 - 1])
            {
                matchedNum[row1 - 1, col1 - 1] = memoryNum[row1 - 1, col1 - 1];
                matchedNum[row2 - 1, col2 - 1] = memoryNum[row2 - 1, col2 - 1];
                displayMatched(matchedNum);
                Console.WriteLine("Matched!");
            }
            else
            {
                displayNotMatched(memoryNum);
                tries--;
                Console.WriteLine("Did not match, Please try again!");
            }

            //if there's no zero in the array, break;
        }


        if(tries == 0) 
            Console.WriteLine("Number of tries exceeded! Play Again?");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [Break;](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) it  terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I know that i need to use break but i don't know how to do it using for loop. If i try 'if(matchedNum[i][j] != 0) break;', it'll ignore the rest of the numbers after that. I'm thinking what if there's zero after that number?

Comment: Are you asking for the `if` condition for your `break`? Cuz from the commented part, I take it you already know you need to `break` the loop somehow.

Comment: @uteist yep! my question has already been answered. I just need to use a counter haha

Comment: Thought so, you could add `int zeroCounter = 0;` and then with every match, you remove one and increase counter by 1. Then you can check it with if and break when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a counter, when it is 16 there are no more zeros to look for.

Comment: thank you! Just what I needed! I forgot that a counter exists haha

Comment: though the counter should be equal to 8 since it increments every matched number given that there's only 8 matched numbers but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement. [More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)